# What's the point of winning more than one battle in Arid Ruins?

Tags: castle-clash

The Arid Ruins challenge consists of 5 battles that you play at real time with other human player (randomly), in escalating difficulty level. As long as you won at least one battle, you will get a prize. (2 chests for free, then you can open more, 300 gems each.)

So far so good, and I expected the prize quality in the chests to change according to amount of battles won, but **that's not the case**.

After playing it daily, I can say for certain: it doesn't matter if I win one battle or four battles (to be honest never got to win all five), the prizes **are the same**.

I've seen lots of players quit after winning the first, probably knowing there's no point wasting time on the other battles, and consider doing it myself too, but thought to ask first: is there any other point winning more than one battle? Is this recorded anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

all you said is right... from my experience (250k might) the only reason i play it its because there is bigger chance to have karmic rock I in the poll. I have never seen them wining 3battles, you will need to win at least 4... 
you may think 1 karmic rock... waste of time.. but it is possible to get more of them.(max i got is 3 in all 5 battles not bad if you are getting them every day.

And yes it is very annoying when players leave the battle... always better to fight with 'friend'

Comment: update on that answer,  from my experience (405k might). ok you can get 1-2 karmic rocks but its useless as you need a hell lot more to do anything this days.